# Why isn't this possible in Python?

Tags: python

```
def myfunc(a,b=2):
    print("Called with", a, b)
    return
p1 = functools.partial(myfunc, b=4)
p1("foobar", 4)
```

Why do I get a syntax error when I run that last line? It works if i do: `myfunc("foobar", 4)`

Comment: Partial creates a new function that calls the old one with some arguments predefined, so then to call the partial function with the same number of arguments as the original function makes no sense. Simply don't pass 4 and it'll work as you intended.

Comment: There's no syntax error, did you mean `TypeError`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'partial' already sets 'b' to 4; if you want another value you should explicitely set parameter 'b':

```
>>> p1("foobar")
('Called with', 'foobar', 4)

>>> p1("foobar", b=5)
('Called with', 'foobar', 5)
```

Comment: I think for a beginner learning python, your answer is too cryptic. Can you explain *why* one "should explicitely set parameter 'b'"? The very first word in the question is "Why", not how.

Comment: You are right. Although the use of 'partial' isn't properly suited for a beginner...

Comment: @Bryan Personally I don't think a beginner in python should use partial at all - at least if they don't come from a functional background. And trying to do `partial(func, b=5)(a, b=4)` really sounds like we're trying to solve the wrong problem.. why use partial there at all?

Comment: @Voo: agreed. I think this answer, without an explanation, is not very good. A beginner needs more information than just "do it this way".

Answer (score 0):

Because you are supplying it with a `b` in `functools.partial` call.
Your call should look like:

```
p1("foobar")
```

or you could just get rid of `b=4` in `p1 = functools.partial(myfunc, b=4)` and make it something like:

```
p1 = functools.partial(myfunc)
```

Comment: Why make a partial with no arguments? Just do ``p1 = myfunc``.

Comment: (I've edited your post so the code blocks are correctly formatted :) there are details about how to get it to work here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because python allows you to use optional parameters in any order. When you work with more statically typed languages, there is usually a constraint on using optional parameters in the order defined in the function/method. So for instance, in python this is legal:

```
def myfunc(a=1,b=2,c=3):
    print a,b,c

myfunc(c=99, b=13, a=12)
```

Because you can specify optional parameters in any order, I think python explicitly needs to know which parameters are assigned to which local function variables.